# Segue to detailed view controller using a button in a cell

Tags: swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell that passes data to a detailed view controller. When the cell is clicked, it segues into a view controller with more details. In the cells, I have a button, when the button is clicked, it also segues into a detailed view controller but a different view controller from when the cell is clicked.

This is what my didselect function looks like.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "details" {


            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]




            if let indexPaths = self.CollectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems{

                let vc = segue.destination as! BookDetailsViewController
                let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
                let indexPath = self.CollectionView!.indexPath(for: cell)
                let post = self.posts[(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let Booked = post["title"] as? String
                let Authors = post["Author"] as? String
                let ISBNS = post["ISBN"] as? String
                let Prices = post["Price"] as? String
                let imageNames = post["image"] as? String
                let imagesTwo = post["imageTwo"] as? String
                let imagesThree = post["imageThree"] as? String
                let imagesFour = post["imageFour"] as? String
                let imagesFive = post["imageFive"] as? String
                vc.Booked = Booked
                vc.Authors = Authors
                vc.ISBNS = ISBNS
                vc.Prices = Prices
                vc.imageNames = imageNames
                vc.imagesTwo = imagesTwo
                vc.imagesThree = imagesThree
                vc.imagesFour = imagesFour
                vc.imagesFive = imagesFive

                print(indexPath?.row)

            }  }

        if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {

            if let indexPaths = self.CollectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems{

                let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
                let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
                let indexPath = self.CollectionView!.indexPath(for: cell)
                let post = self.posts[(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let username = post["username"] as? String
                let userpicuid = post["uid"] as? String
                vc.username = username
                vc.userpicuid = userpicuid


                print(indexPath?.row)

            }}}
```

For if the segue == User's Profile I get an error in the let cell = line. My button in the cell was created in the cellForItemAt collection view function

```
    let editButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 106, y: 171, width: 36, height: 36))

    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    editButton.tag = indexPath.row
    print(indexPath.row)
    editButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    cell.addSubview(editButton)
```

When I click the cell, it works perfectly and segues me into a detailed view controller but when I click the button within the cell, I get an error. 
[image]

Here is my editTappedButton function

```
    @IBAction func editButtonTapped() -> Void {
            print("Hello Edit Button")

performSegue(withIdentifier: "UsersProfile", sender: self)

        }
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: @publicstaticvoid it has been posted

Comment: Can you add the editButtonTapped function. From the error, it seems the problem is when you are casting `let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell`. What is the result when you just print sender?

Comment: what do you mean by just print sender? @TristanBeaton

Comment: @juelizabeth Are you performing segue in your button action?

Comment: Just after function prepare for segue at the start of the function, put 'print(sender)'. This should print out the class of the sender. I think it isn't going to print out UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: @NiravD no, the segue is being performed in the didselectItemAt function

Comment: @juelizabeth But there is no code of performSegue in didSelect also is your segue connected from cell to destinationVC or SourceVC to destinationVC or you are having both segue?

Comment: @NiravD the segue is connected from the source view controller to the destination view controller, if segue identifier is under override func prepare for segue, I can't write override func prepare for segue twice or i get an error

Comment: @juelizabeth Add the call `performSegue` in your question

Comment: @NiravD when i click on the cell, it just prints out hello edit button

Comment: @juelizabeth What I'm asking is where you are calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifer", sender: anything)`

Comment: @NiravD I called it in the editButtonTapped function which it worked. it segued but it didn't send the information to the detailed view controller

Comment: @juelizabeth Then you need to show that code add that in your question what argument you are passing with sender

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143965/discussion-between-juelizabeth-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that you are getting that crash because with your button action you are calling `performSegue(withIdentifier: "UsersProfile", sender: self)` now with sender you are passing `self` means reference of current controller not the `UICollectionViewCell` what you need is get the indexPath of that cell and pass that and now in `prepareForSegue` cast the sender to `IndexPath` instead of `UICollectionViewCell`.

First replace your `editButtonTapped` with below one

```
@IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        print("Hello Edit Button")

    let point = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point!) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "UsersProfile", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Now in `prepareForSegue` for identifier `UsersProfile` cast the `sender` to `IndexPath` or simply replace your condition with my one.

```
if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {

    if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath{
        let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let username = post["username"] as? String
        let userpicuid = post["uid"] as? String
        vc.username = username
        vc.userpicuid = userpicuid
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly!! Thank you so much for the solution and especially the explanation!